# How to save public key in SSL certificate messages using OpenSsl?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, public-key

I want to save the public key and its algorithm in SSL Certificates messages.

in OpenSSL library, I found a function named public_key_type which returns public key algorithm. but to extract public key, I found just a function named evp_PKEY_print_public, which prints public key. but I don't want to print it. my goal is to save it in a structure.
anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

From your question, it is not entirely clear to me what you mean by "to save it in a structure". But I can explain how you can get access to the actual public key stored in your certificate, so you can do what you want with it.

First, you can use the following to get a hold of the certificate's public key, in its generic format:

```
EVP_PKEY *pubkey = X509_get_pubkey(cert);
/* If it is not NULL, do what needs to be done with pubkey */
EVP_PKEY_free(pubkey);
```

See [the documentation of `X509_get_pubkey()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/X509_REQ_set_pubkey.html) for more information.

Now that you have this generic public key, you can use [its lower-level key accessors](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/EVP_PKEY_type.html) to get access to the underlying public key in its specific format. For example:

```
RSA *rsapubkey = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pubkey);
if (NULL != rsapubkey) {
    printf("This cert has an RSA public key\n");
    /* Do your stuff with the RSA key, for example using RSA_get0_key()
       for current versions of OpenSSL, or directly access the fields
       rsapubkey->n and rsapubkey->e for older versions */
    RSA_free(rsapubkey);
}
```

The function `EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA()` returns `NULL` if the underlying key is not an RSA key. Otherwise, you can use it to get access to the modulus (`n`) and exponent (`e`), which is basically all you need to "save" it. Or you can hold on to `rsapubkey`, since it contains all public key information. You have to `RSA_free()` it when you are done.

Similarly, you can use `EVP_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY()` if you expect an EC key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. can you write an example how to access to module and exponent after using EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA() function?

It seems that RSA_get0_key() is'nt exist in openssl/rsa.h library.

Comment: @Saeed: what version of OpenSSL are you using?

Comment: I'm using OpenSSL 1.0.1.

Comment: @Saeed I added some instructions to the answer for older OpenSSL version. If that is not sufficient to solve your problem, you will have to provide more information about what you are trying to achieve, probably in a different question.